# error: At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required (Windows 10)

Tags: omnet++

I have tried to installed INET4.0.0 with OMNET 5.4.1 on Windows 10. 
I have a lot of errors.

```
In file included from inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppClient.cc:22:
In file included from .\inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppClient.h:21:
.\inet/common/INETDefs.h:45:4: error: At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required
#  error At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required
   ^
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1554: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/base/ApplicationPacketSerializer.o] Error 1
In file included from inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppServer.cc:21:
In file included from .\inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppServer.h:21:
.\inet/common/INETDefs.h:45:4: error: At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required
#  error At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required
   ^
In file included from inet/applications/ethernet/EthernetApplication.cc:14:
In file included from .\inet/applications/ethernet/EtherApp_m.h:37:
In file included from .\inet/common/INETDefs_m.h:33:
.\inet/common/INETDefs.h:45:4: error: At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required
#  error At least OMNeT++/OMNEST version 5.4.1 required
   ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1554: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/dhcp/DhcpServer.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1554: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/dhcp/DhcpClient.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1554: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppClient.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1554: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppServer.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1554: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/ethernet/EthernetApplication.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/omnetpp-5.4/samples/inet4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

It is due to #define OMNETPP_BUILDNUM   1019. Inet gives an error when  OMNETPP_BUILDNUM < 1020.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Regards,
Thiha Kyaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using OMNeT++ 5.4.1 but instead omnet 5.4 only. The `OMNETPP_BUILDNUM` is 1020 in the 5.4.1 version. Check whether you indeed updated and using the latest version.